# air bag light stuck on

Tags: buick, supplemental-restraint-system, warning-light, century

when I turn my car on the air bag light blinks about 7 times and it stays on. Not sure how to handle this or determine the problem. I hear it can be 400 -1000 to get this fixed and handled I'd like to avoid that

Its a 2003 buick century '
where should I take it I don't have my own mechanic.

Comment: Note that the blinking is the normal power-on test.  Staying lit is the issue.  A special code scanner is needed to read the airbag controller - the basic one at the auto parts store won't do it.

Comment: http://www.airbagcenter.com/StaticPages/SelectStaticPage.aspx?content=70

Answer (score 4):

To handle this I would advise you to take it to have the airbag system scanned to see if a trouble code exists.

For us to simply just tell you what the issue is we are going to need more information, such as:

- Have you experienced a wreck recently?
- Have you done any adjustments to the steering wheel?
- Have you spun the steering wheel?
- Have you examined the fuse to check to see if it ok?
- Have you removed the dash or do anything within the dash?

The airbag system is not something you want to go around guessing on what may be an issue or what is the matter.  If your light is on then you could face an inoperable air bag system and if you were to experience a wreck it could lead to someone loosing their life.  If you go around and start messing with an air bag system without knowledge you could accidentally deploy an air bag and that could result in hurting someone.

Comment: I haven't done anything to the car recently. I will check the fuse.

Comment: changed the fuse but the air bag light still stays stuck